# FullPage.js - Blank page after using fp-auto-height-responsive / height:auto;

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, height, fullpage.js

I'm using this wonderful plugin FullPage.js and everything is working perfectly beside one thing...

It's a very specific problem but I'm trying to make my website a bit responsive so I used the option:

> responsiveWidth: 1023

So you can scroll on the website like a normal website. And then I wanted the height of each of my slides to be adjusted to this content so I used:

> fp-auto-height-responsive

which basically is setting the height to auto:

```
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive.fp-section,
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-slide,
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-tableCell {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

But because of that, when I reach 1023px, my website/the plugin is not loading anymore... The problem is obviously only on my website and I tried everything (disable every css files one by one, desactivated others plugins, try to not use position absolute in my content,...) The only thing that seems working when I inspect locally is to get ride of this height:auto... But I really need the height to be adjusted since every slide on my website is made with a 3 boxes layout (to make each of them full width when below 1024px)

I know my problem is very specific and someone has any ideas to help me solving this, I would really apreciate!

Thanks

Comment: Impossible to help without a reproduction.